# callkit does not navigate to the call view in sinch

Tags: ios, sinch, callkit

In sinch for IOS, when using the SinchCallKit example project I noticed the app does not navigate to correct page when navigating from the callkit view

When I receive a call I can answer using callkit, and then I can tap the sinch button to return to the sinch app.
I expect the sinch app to open on the Call View Controller page.
However it opens with the Main View Controller.
What changes would be required to implement this?

The example files can be downloaded [here](https://www.sinch.com/downloads/?utm_source=Sinch%20Tier%201%20Newsletter%20Q4%202017&utm_campaign=2f2db96d4a-Sinch_Tier1_Newsletter_AUGUST_2017&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_b84268f342-2f2db96d4a-133276297)

Comment: Check whether this key "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" is not in your plist file. Another one issue can be that your app is killed by the OS when a high memory usage occurred.

Comment: @MidhunMP that key is not in there, also the app is not killed since nothing shows up in the console and the call doesn't lose it's connection

Comment: its a known bug, we have it on our backlog to fix